# Jetty : Multiple webapps on different instances not working

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, jetty, jetty-9

I am working on a Spring-MVC application which we are currently deploying on Jetty-9.4. I have 2 different Jetty folders each with their http-port, https-port and jetty-port in jetty.xml. Also, in each of them I have added a single `ROOT.war` application. Even after that, when I start the 2nd Jetty instance, I get a message, Jetty instance already running.

**Am I missing something?**

1st instance jetty.xml :

```
  <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
      <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
      <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8446" /></Set>
</New>
```

1st instance jetty-ssl.xml

```
<Call  name="addConnector">
  <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="8446" /></Set>
</Arg>
  </Call>
```

1st instance jetty-http.xml :

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
  <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.http.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="8086" /></Set>
  </Arg>
  </Call>
```

2nd instance jetty.xml :

```
<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
  <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
  <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8444" /></Set>
```

2nd instance jetty-ssl.xml :

```
<Call  name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
<Call  name="addConnector">
 <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" deprecated="ssl.port" default="8444" /></Set>
```

2nd instance jetty-http.xml

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="httpConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
   </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.http.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.http.port" deprecated="jetty.port" default="8085" /></Set>
```

Comment: Can you provide the run time arguments that you are using to start the instances?

Comment: @anchreg : I am simply calling jetty.sh start from bin folder for both.

Comment: check the JETTY_HOME, I think both your instances point to the same installation. A dump of the ps command would be useful